# How do I calculate ibeacon route with application?

Tags: signals, coordinates, ibeacon-android

Ibeacon sends id and proximity to android application. But I need to calculate where is Ibecon to application(phone). So I have to know where signal comes from and I can calculate x,y coordinates. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build navigation based on beacons, you should first know the X,Y positions of them. Then, if you have at least three beacons with known fixed positions, you can use trilateration or triangulation to figure out the user's position in relation to those fixed points.

It also requires lots of noise reduction depending on the accuracy you're looking for, but that's a different discussion I suppose.

Cheers.

Comment: Does ibeacon have x,y position ? My purpose is to find where I should to place them. Because of that, I need to percieve its location to me. As you said, it is not possible with 1 ibeacon. Well, what should I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: It's up to you what are the X,Y positions: you need to first create a coordinate system and it's your decision how you design it. Basically, you choose the 0,0 point. You can also give Estimote Indoor Location SDK a try, it might be helpful for you: http://estimote.com/indoor/